# Solaris 11 SMB server sometimes becomes unreachable for some Windows XP clients

Tags: solaris, server-message-block

I've got a Solaris 11 box acting as a NAS/SAN for both a small virtualised environment (over iSCSI and NFS), as well as a central filestore for a global team (over SMB). It works fine for most people, but every now and again I get a report from a couple of guys over in the US (I'm in UK) that they can't reach the network share.

The specific message Windows reports is: `\\10.1.1.1\share is not accessible [...] The semaphore timeout period has expired.`

In Solaris, I've enabled some debug logging and notice that when this happens, I see entries in `/var/adm/messages` similar to:

```
Sep  7 00:02:48 lonsbrndnas01 smbd[24587]: [ID 208731 daemon.debug] WORKGROUP         <1D> flags=0x0 
Sep  7 00:02:48 lonsbrndnas01 smbd[24587]: [ID 370951 daemon.debug]   10.13.111.34 ttl=300 flags=0x0 port=35328
Sep  7 00:04:39 lonsbrndnas01 smbsrv: [ID 421734 kern.notice] NOTICE: [LONSBRNDNAS01\guest]: filestream.hdr share not found
Sep  7 00:04:39 lonsbrndnas01 smbsrv: [ID 421734 kern.notice] NOTICE: [LONSBRNDNAS01\guest]: filestream.hdr share not found
```

and

```
Sep  6 20:53:12 lonsbrndnas01 smbsrv: [ID 421734 kern.notice] NOTICE: [NT Authority\Anonymous]: share access denied: IPC only
Sep  6 20:53:12 lonsbrndnas01 smbsrv: [ID 421734 kern.notice] NOTICE: [NT Authority\Anonymous]: share access denied: IPC only
Sep  6 20:53:46 lonsbrndnas01 last message repeated 2 times
```

This issue is resolved by restarting the smb server daemon on the Solaris server. The WinXP client can then access it.

I have two questions:

1. What's causing this?
2. Is there any way for Solaris to report the IP address of the connecting client when it encounters an error? At the moment it's difficult to match up error messages to clients.